# How to set @NotEmpty annotation messages in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, javax.validation

In a Java (+ Spring Boot) project, there is a notation using `javax.validation` as shown below:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "validation.product.notEmpty")
private String product;

@NotEmpty(message = "validation.username.password")
private String password;
```

I have a look at the usage of them, but there are some points that I could not understand:

**1.** Is there a special usage e.g. conditional message displaying for `validation.username.password`? For example if username field is null, then display this message? Or is it completely the same manner as the `product` field?

**2.** I search the project, but could not find `validation.product.notEmpty` or `validation.username.password`. So, how do they work? I think there should be a definition for these messages, but as I did not find, is it come from default messages of `javax.validation`?

Comment: For point #2 don't you have a `ValidationMessages.properties` file in your project where those keys exist? Or any other *.properties file?

Comment: Could you please paste the package of @EmailRegex and its code? I don't find this annotation

Comment: @pleft Yes, `text.properties` exists, but these keys are not added to that file and I think it may be missed or there may be a special usage. So, in this case it must be added to that file, right?

Comment: @japhy Thanks, #1 was changed. Any reply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is the difference between @EmailRegex and @Email? And is there
>    any need to also use @NotEmpty with these @EmailRegex or @Email
>    annotations?

`@Email` will not throw error for an empty String. So you need `@NotEmpty` to be sure that this String is not empty if you always require an email to be there.

`@Email` will consider valid everything that is in the form `blabla@blabla.blabla`. If you want to further constraint this you can use `@EmailRegex` so that you allow only `blabla@blabla.eu` by defining your own regular expression.

`@EmailRegex` does not seem to be included in hibernate annotations or spring annotations. So it is either a custom annotation imported from somewhere else or just a custom annotation of your application. Inspect the code to see how it actually behaves but from it's name I suppose it behaves as I have explained above.

> 2. I search the project, but could not find validation.product.notEmpty
>    or validation.username.password. So, how do they work? I think there
>    should be a definition for these messages, but as I did not find, is
>    it come from default messages of javax.validation?

It should be with **{....}** so  like `@NotEmpty(message = "{validation.username.password}") private String password;`. In that case Spring will automatically read properties from the property files and apply the value for the property `validation.username.password`. If it does not exist then go to either application.properties or application.yaml and add that property.

**Some more notes on this last one**. I have seen some strange cases in backend-frontend applications which might be your case here.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "validation.username.password")
```

The actual message thrown here when the validation fails is `validation.username.password`. I have seen cases where the frontend then reads that message and binds a value to this one. I have seen this to be used when frontend supports multiple languages and binds another value for each language each time. This would explain why you don't have { } or such a property in your application.

```
 @NotEmpty(message = "{validation.username.password}")
```

with an existing property `validation.username.password= password can not be empty`
will have as a result when the validation fails the message `password can not be empty` to be delivered.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For #2, do you mean that there must a a line e.g. `validation.username.password=Wrong username or password.` in my corresponding `text.properties` file to display the message for `validation.username.password`?

Comment: On the other hand, do I have to use `{ }` or is it also ok to use like `@NotEmpty(message = "validation.username.password") ` ?

Comment: yes you have to use { }  in order for spring to be able to bind a value from a properties file